# How to use Scipy Rotation for transforming Orientations between Coordinate Systems with the help of euler angles?

Tags: python, scipy

So lets assume my body has the following extrinsic orientation in the Coordinate System A:

```
A = [20,30,40] # extrinsic xyz in degrees
```

And the following Orientation in the Coordinate System B:

```
B = [10, 25, 50]
```

So the transformation from A to B is:

```
T = [-10, -5, 10]
```

So that:

```
B = A + T
```

Now I want to do the same using scipy.Rotation:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

A = Rotation.from_euler('xyz' ,[20, 30, 40], degrees=True)
B = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', [10, 25, 50], degrees=True)
T = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', [-10, -5, 10], degrees=True)
result =  A  * T # This seems to be wrong?

print(result.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)) # Output: [14.02609598 21.61478378 48.20912092]
```

Where is my mistake here? What am I doint wrong. I need to use scipy rotation because, I will apply that same rotation given in euler angles on quaternions too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation from A to B is **incorrect**. You need to be careful when considering rotations in 3D as rotations about different axes do not commute with each other.

According to your understanding, the T in the following code should get the object to [0, 0, 0]. But it doesn't.

```
A = Rotation.from_euler('xyz' ,[20, 30, 40], degrees=True)
T = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', [-20, -30, -40], degrees=True)
result =  A * T
print(result.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)) 
# output: [-25.4441408    5.14593816  -4.1802616 ]
```

However, if you reverse the order of the rotations, you go to [0, 0, 0] as expected.

```
A = Rotation.from_euler('xyz' ,[20, 30, 40], degrees=True)
T = Rotation.from_euler('zyx', [-40, -30, -20], degrees=True)
result =  A * T
print(result.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)) 

# output: [ 4.77083202e-15  0.00000000e+00 -1.98784668e-15] practically [0,0,0]
```

The correct transformation from A to B will be `T = [-14.74053552, -1.237896,  10.10094351]`. Refer to the following.

```
A = Rotation.from_euler('xyz' ,[20, 30, 40], degrees=True)
AToZero = Rotation.from_euler('zyx', [-40, -30, -20], degrees=True)
ZeroToB = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', [10, 25, 50], degrees=True)
T = AToZero*ZeroToB
print(T.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True))
# output: [-14.74053552  -1.237896    10.10094351]
result =  A * T
print(result.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)) 
# ouput: [10. 25. 50.]
```

Comment: But your calculated T would not work for any other point? 

Like if I would apply it on A = Rotation.from_euler('xyz' ,[50, 50, 50], degrees=True), the results would be [40.63424024 41.20306892 57.34280162] instead of [40, 45 ,60]

Comment: It wouldn't. The transformation matrix is initial condition dependent.

Comment: But is there no possibility to get a general transformation between the coordinate system? In your way we already need the result to get the transformation? So we do not gain anything from that?

Comment: To go from source to destination, you need to know both to know the transformation. This is the general transformation to transform the orientation of objects in one frame to another frame. I don't understand what you mean by "general transformation". Help me understand what you need.

Comment: Imagine following example: 
I have a camera on a drone with which I took some Photos in the real world, I know the correct Orientation and Position of the camera in the real world. No with these photos and photogrammetry I can create a mesh of the environment, but that mesh would be in an arbitrary coordinate system that I do not know. The only thing I know is the Pose of the Images, with which I created the mesh, in the world frame and in the mesh  frame. Know imagine I am doing a second flight and want to transform the camera pose to the mesh, I know would need some general transformation

Comment: Try to find the orientation of mesh frame in the world frame or vice versa by using the two poses. Without that your job will be difficult. What you are call as a general transformation is not what a transformation means conventionally. In your scenario, mesh frame and world frame are the two frames of reference. So if you know the orientation of an object in one frame you can find the orientation of that object in the other frame by using the transformation matrix between the two frames. Its a 3x3 orthogonal matrix. So you need to estimate 6 numbers using the poses you have.